# QGIS creating batch folder directory with incremented names by using Python console

Tags: qgis, python, batch, directory

I have the directory, where I have to store all the items separately in the list of folders. This list includes exactly the same folders only with incrementing number, as you can see below:

[image]

Because I am going to have more than 200 folders, I decided to create all of them by using Python console in QGIS.

My approach so far looks as you can see below:

```
 import os
 path='C:\\Users\\mk\\Desktop\\AX\\Pre survey\\Tyton'
 os.chdir(path)
 for i in range (1,208):
 Newfolder='Strand-' + str(i)
 os.makedirs(Newfolder)
```

As per the tutorial below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nr0eW3w1u4&ab_channel=PyBTV

Since I managed to create one folder, there is a problem with the batch of these folders.

First of all, I cannot put something like **"leading 0"**, as I tried:

```
    for i in range (001,208)
```

I cannot do this, but I need the folder numeration as shown in the image.

Another issue is, that if I use the whole code presented, Python throws an error:

**IndentationError: expected an indented block**

debugging the following line:

```
    Newfolder='Strand-' + str(i)
```

The examples how to solve this error are here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446366/why-am-i-getting-indentationerror-expected-an-indented-block

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level

but i couldn't apply them to my situation.

How can I do the batch directory creation with Python, preferably by QGIS python console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import os
path='C:\\Users\\mk\\Desktop\\AX\\Pre survey\\Tyton\\'
os.chdir(path)
for i in range (1,208):
    newfolder=path + 'Strand-' + str(format(i, '03'))
    os.mkdir(newfolder)
```

About your errors:

- wrong indentation means you need to indent your codeblock of a loop, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-how-do-i-fix-it/45621723#45621723 for a great answer on this topic. Usually this is done by a `TAB` or `four whitespaces`.
- `for i in range (001,208)` wont work, as 001 is not a number. Instead you can format your current `i` by using `format()`: `str(format(i, '03')`
- to create one folder, use `os.mkdir()`

Comment: Nothing happens. Maybe is something to add?

Comment: OK I see that it works, but the path is slightly wrong, as the folders aren't created at the path:
path='C:\\Users\\mk\\Desktop\\AX\\Pre survey\\Tyton\\'
but here:
path='C:\\Users\\mk\\Desktop\\AX\\Pre survey\\'
it's simply one folder up. What is missing here then?

Comment: Yes! I found an error! I forgot about \\ at the very end of my path. hence Python saved my folders in one level up and added the Tyton prefix. Thanks a lot!